# Calculate the area of all those squares, whose 2 corners are on the parabola and 2 remaining are on the x axis

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, analysis

You have a parabola $y=x^2-12x+36$. Calculate the area of all those squares, whose $2$ corners are on the given parabola and $2$ remaining are on the $x$-axis

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please use MathJax to write questions. Also it is appreciated if you show what approach you have taken and where you got stuck

Answer (score 2):

You can start with the fact that if there is a square it has to be centred around the parabola. This means that it's around the point $(6,0)$. So we assume one corner is some $h$ distance to the left of it and one is $h$ distance to the right. This gives us the points $(6- h,0)$ and $(6+h,0)$. Now for it to be a square two vertical lines will go up from this point to meet the parabola. The vertical distance must be equal to the total horizontal distance which is $(6+h)-(6-h)=2h$.
To find out the vertical distance evaluate where the vertical lines will meet the parabola by putting in the $x=6-h$ and $x=6+h$.

$$y= (x-6)^2=(6-h-6)^2=h^2$$

So the vertical distance is $h^2$. Equating the vertical and the horizontal distances, we get

$$2h=h^2$$
$$h=2$$
and
$$h=0$$

$h=0$ is not allowed as it gives us a single point for all corners. When we put $h=2$, we get the $x$-axis points as $(4,0)$ and $(8,0)$. So the side of a square is $d=8-4=4$. Hence the area is $A=4\cdot4=16$